# Crimping tool where to crimp

Tags: connector, identification, wiring, crimp

I have a very cheap crimping tool and am trying to confirm where to crimp to ensure a good connection is made.

I’m using red 18awg wire but the dot doesn’t really align with a spot like most crimpers. I’ve already done a few on the spot where it says “insul and” as my connector has insulated heat shrink over it. Is this the right spot to do it? I can’t find any similar crimpers that confirm this is correct. [image: crimping tool][image: connector crimped]

Comment: please show the result of your attempt ... there is no way to confirm something invisible

Comment: I can certainly add that but the question was more of if that is the correct place to place the wire with the connector, on the part lining up with “insul and” or would it be somewhere else on the tool?

Comment: My take is that all insulated crimps go under the insulated crimp bump, and all unisulated crimps go under the uninsulated bump. However, just do whatever works for now and start saving up for a better crimp tool. Ideally a ratcheting tool.

Comment: squeeze the pink insulation around the wire using the small opening to left of the word INSULATION

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That tool doesn't look like it has separate jaws for insulated and non-insulated terminals. That "INSUL AND NON INSUL" looks like it is a single label meant to apply to both of the leftmost jaws with the one on the left being 16-10AWG and the second leftmost being 22-18AWG.

Comment: Gotcha so would I be able to recrimp the connector on the jaw lining up with the “non-insul” line if I’m using 18AWG wire? I don’t know why they don’t clearly label or explain which is which in the product description or maybe I’m just missing something. Thanks

Comment: @hstan4 Yes. It's because that style of crimping tools are low quality. The lowest quality crimping quality tool I would use that does not have a ratchet is something that looks like this: https://www.kleintools.com/sites/all/product_assets/catalog_imagery/klein/j1005.jpg

Comment: Bummer. Hopefully it’ll suffice with my small project until an upgrade makes sense. And just to make sure, it’s that jaw On the same side as the non insul line and not the jaw between the two lines? Sorry if that’s confusing just want to ensure my connections don’t short!

Comment: @hstan4 The hills, not the valleys.

Comment: The hills on the top side (with the color labels) or bottom side? Thank you for the help

Comment: @hstan4 As oriented in your photo. Hills only face up.

Comment: Thank you! Very helpful